# Comparing two NSDictionaries and deleting if keys don't match

Tags: ios, compare, nsdictionary

In my app I'm using two NSMutableDictionaries. Lets call them basicDictionary and refreshDictionary.

In basicDictionary I have values, lets say

key:"1" value:"2000" photo:someUIImage //Lets say I want to track score of player
key:"2" value:"1500" photo:someUIImage2
key:"3" value:"1500" photo:someUIImage3
key:"4" value:"1500" photo:someUIImage4

key stands for player id and rest is pretty clear.

I do server api call every 20 sec to refresh score of players. Because I don't want to load photo as well im using refresh call to bring me only player id and his actual score.

So every 20 secs I get data that I save in refreshDictionary. There are only ids and current score of that id.

refreshDictionary example:

key:"1" value:"2500"
key:"2" value:"2800"
key:"3" value:"2700"

I update my tableView with new values. As you can see, I got data only for 3 players, because player 4 has deleted his profile. Now my question is, how do I update basicDictionary to remove player 4?

I know that I'm supposed tu use `if (!([basicDictionary isEqualToDictionary:refreshDictionary))`
however, it won't tell me at which key they aren't equal.

So what would you guys do? Should I iterate through both of them in nested loop? That seems to consume alot of time when dictionaries are bigger. Oh by the way, my dictionaries are always sorted same way (by players id)

My idea is, that I compare these two dictionaries in

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        if (refresh)
        { //compare dictionaries and modify basicDictionary that is data source for my tableview by deleting where key doesn't match
}
```

Comment: Extract the keys from both (read the NSDictionary doc to see how), sort the two NSArrays containing the keys (since they will be in random order), and then walk through the two NSArrays side-by-side to find what's missing.  Note that this sort of side-by-side comparison is just a hair tricky -- you need to maintain two separate indices for the two arrays you're "walking".

Comment: I mean I could probably do it like this NSArray *keys = [basicDict allKeys]; NSArray *keys2 = [refreshDict allkeys];

for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < keys2.count; j++)
    {
         if ([[keys objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:[keys2 ObjectAtIndex:j]])
         {
             // insert code here
         }
    }
} but I think, it'll take alot of time Edit: bleh comments are hard to format .. I mean using nested loop and for each key of basicDict try to compare it with each key of refreshDict

Comment: Actually, if this is a one-way relationship it's much simpler.  Extract the keys from the list which may have had keys removed.  Loop through that list and see if the key is in the other dictionary or not.  No need for a nested loop in any case.

Comment: If I dare ask: why not just use an `NSURLCache` to prevent duplicate image fetches and parse the dictionaries naturally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will give you keys that changed:

*NOTE: as the lookup of keys is basically jumping into a hashmap (an o1 op), you dont have to worry about the 2nd array walk you talk about*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (changedKeys)
- (NSArray*)changedKeysIn:(NSDictionary*)d;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (changedKeys)
- (NSArray*)changedKeysIn:(NSDictionary*)d {
    NSMutableArray *changedKs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(id k in self) {
        if(![[self objectForKey:k] isEqual:[d objectForKey:k]])
            [changedKs addObject:k];
    }
    return changedKs;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDictionary *d1 = @{@"1":@"value",@"2":@"value",@"3":@"value",@"4":@"value"};
        NSDictionary *d2 = @{@"1":@"value",@"2":@"newvalue",@"3":@"value"};

        NSArray *ks = [d1 changedKeysIn:d2];
        NSLog(@"%@", ks);   

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: self.allKeys changed to just self -- a dictionary can be enumerated already

Comment: No need for `self.allKeys` -- plain `self` will work, because `NSFastEnumeration` on a dictionary enumerates the keys. Better yet, use [`-[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:) to get both the keys and values at the same time.